# unexpected token < using script tag

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I copied the exact code from google analytic still but seeing error in my browser's console

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-6876886-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

above code I put in a ga.js file. What's wrong? I'm lost.

Comment: This is if you are including it directly in HTML. If it is in its own _.js_ file, omit the `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put javascript in `html`, you enclose it within `<script>...</script>` tags.

But when you write javascript in `.js` file, then you have to omit those tags.